# increment the textbox using multithreading

Tags: c#, forms

I want to create a C# form in which two text box show two different numbers.
After clicking on start button both numbers should start incrementing at same time should increment slowly so we can see them increment and clicking on stop button should stop increment.
Both text box are not related to each other any way.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(increment1));

    public static int fNumber = 0, sNumber = 0,flag = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t1.Start();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void number1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public static void increment1()
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        for (int i = fNumber;i<1000;i++)
        {
            frm.number1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u try something? ... should that numbers increment every second?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. Dont put it in a comment

Comment: You should try something first. There's no fun in programming if others would code it for you. Regarding your goal, one approach is the use of timers.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `Form1` which is wrong. Use the current `Form1` that started the `Thread`.

Try

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer timer1;

    public static int fNumber = 0, sNumber = 0,flag = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void number1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int.TryParse(this.number1.Text, out i);
        i++;
        if(this.number1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.number1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() 
            {
                this.number1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
            });    
        }
        else
        {
            this.number1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
        }
    }
}
```

For safety measures, check if invoking is required. 
Replace `this.number1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);` with this block of code.

```
 if(this.number1.InvokeRequired)
 {
     this.number1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() 
     {
         this.number1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
     });    
 }
 else
 {
     this.number1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
 }
```

Comment: says this not valid in static property

Comment: Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer.

Comment: @Ajay try my updated answer. Moved the initialization of the `Thread t1` inside the constructor because a non-static `increment1` is not yet defined  which will still result in build error.

Comment: @Ajay try my updated answer. Changed `Thread` to `Timer`. Assuming `button4` is used for stopping, it should now work.

Comment: The value increments in a flash ,I need it to be slow to see the increment happen

Comment: @Ajay see the updated code. Change the timer's interval using `timer1.Interval = 1000;`. This number is in milliseconds.

Comment: waits for some time and increments in a flash.

Comment: @Ajay copy the `timer1_Tick` as is. Do not use the `for-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Increment1()
{
    for (int i = fNumber;i<1000;i++)
    {
        number1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
        number2.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
    }
}
```

And just generally avoid static for threads. You can access your textboxes directly without the word this if you named your textboses number1 and number2. In a static method the variables need to be static aswell or you will get a compilation error.

For visibility, functions should have first letter in upper case. So you can distinguish them more easily from variables.